# Admob for differnet apps using Product flavor

Tags: android, admob, android-productflavors

I have multiple app with same code base. So I Implemented **product flavor** to achieve it.

> Google ads not showing when I change **applicationId** in product flavor but it's wokring for **applicationIdSuffix**

```
    flavorDimensions "prod"
    productFlavors {
        generalKnowledge {
            applicationId "droidudes.general.knowledge.quiz"
            ///applicationIdSuffix '.general'
            dimension "prod"
        }
        physicsQuiz {
            applicationId "droidudes.physics.mcq.trivia.quiz"
            ///applicationIdSuffix '.physics'
            dimension "prod"
        }
    }
```

Code is pushed at [**github Repo**](https://github.com/IMDroidude/AdmobRND)

Answer (score 0):

In your adMob account, you have to create package including applicationIdSuffix

namely

> com.app.id.general

and

> com.app.id.physics

Answer (score 0):

> I simply clean my project twice then Rebuild it

Afterwards I try cache invalidate and restart.

Doing this kind of stuff along with assembleDebug from Gradle option resolve my issue.

This issue may be due to android studio build or gradle.